# How do you make Chromium command line switches on a Chromebook?

Tags: chromium, google-chrome-os, chromebook, chromium-os

I recently saw that ChromeOS added the functionality to do split screen windows in tablet mode in the most recent dev releases.  So I put my Chromebook R11 in dev mode for the first time and updated to version 62.

The flag is one of the many on this list https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

The only resources for actually executing these switches was http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags

So I tried following the steps. I went to the crosh shell with Ctrl-Alt-T.  Then I typed "shell". Then "sudo su".  Then I tried to modify with "sudo vim /etc/chrome_dev.conf", but it was readonly so it didn't save.

So I visited here  www dot chromium dot org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device and followed the steps to making changes to the filesystem and disabling rootfs verification. But the command it told me to enter just gave me an error: "make_dev_ssd.sh: ERROR: IMAGE /dev/mmcblk0 IS NOT MODIFIED."

I'm running out of ideas and resources here..

Answer (score 0):

`make_dev_ssd.sh` is how you disable rootfs verification and modify files in the rootfs.  If that's not working, that might be a bug in that script that should be reported & fixed upstream (e.g. https://crbug.com/new).

That said, are you sure you need to pass a command line flag ?  Look at `chrome://flags` and see if the feature you want to access is available there.  Many command line flag is also available on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo su
cp /etc/chrome_dev.conf /usr/local/
mount --bind /usr/local/chrome_dev.conf /etc/chrome_dev.conf
echo "--arc-availability=officially-supported " >> /etc/chrome_dev.conf
```